# does not generate async method in T4MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, t4mvc

I used T4MVC version `3.16.0` and I have method like this :

```
public async virtual Task<JsonResult> Read([ModelBinder(typeof(DataTablesBinder))] IDataTablesRequest requestModel)
{
    //call async method here
}
```

I run `T4MVC.tt` but when I call that method like this:

```
@Url.Action(MVC.admin.News.Read())
```

I get compiler error like that:

> No overload for method in T4MVC

I use Visual Studio 2013 and ASP.NET MVC 5.2

What is wrong ?

Comment: this problem fixed in version `3.17` . I `Uninstall` `T4MVC `and installed it again , its works fine know .

Answer (score 2):

run custom tool by right click on t4mvc or if not worked for u delete t4mvc and setup again.It solve ur problem.